# Is turnover just for businesses

Tags: word-usage

In a company or business the amount of money that you take in is usually referred to as turnover, but if you are a public authority (Local Council) where the money comes in the form of taxation and government funding and goes out to suppliers for services not for the organisation (eg schools, home care etc). What would that still qualify as turnover or is there a more appropriate term.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75831/discussion-on-question-by-naz-is-turnover-just-for-businesses).

Comment: Is this a "meaning" question or a "word-request" question? We can only ask one Q is suppose.

Answer (score 2):

The term **"turnover"** in the United States is primarily a business term, and is always related to a period of time, e.g., the number of times inventory "turns over" in a year, or the length of time it takes for inventory to sell (and be replaced by new inventory).  I gather from comments moved to "chat" that in Britain and Asia the time period is typically a year.

I agree with the @esurfsnake that governments would use the term receipts or revenue.  Receipts in the United States is broader than revenue; revenue relates to tax receipts, but governments (federal, state, or local) also get other kinds of receipts--import duties, fines, fees for services, and so forth.

If you have a store with goods that cost $50,000 that you expect to sell for $75,000, the question is this: how often does that happen in a year?

The term also applies to employee turnover (on average, how long do new hires stay on the job?).  And it applies to how often a restaurant seats a new set of customers.  My favorite restaurant has a turnover time of about two hours, so in a typical evening they get two seatings, at about 5:30 p.m. and 7:30 p.m.

Here's investopedia on turnover: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/t/turnover.asp

Answer (score 1):

This is distinctly British English.

In the U.S., 'revenue' is the money received by a company, non-profit, or government.

In the UK, 'turnover' is revenue received by a company. Governments usually call it 'receipts'.

> In the UK, revenue, or sales, are often called “turnover”. According to the Companies Act, turnover is:
>
> “The amount derived from the provisions of goods or services within the company’s ordinary activities after deduction of trade discounts, VAT and other relevant taxes”
>
> [- What is turnover](https://www.starfishaccounting.co.uk/what-is-turnover/) (by Georgi Rollings, Starfish Accounting)

Comment: Can you clarify if BrE *turnover* can include revenue from services, investments, contracts, or if it is specifically from moving (turning over) product inventory?

Comment: This is incorrect . Please provide evidence of what you are saying.

Comment: I have  been to business school and run companies in both the UK and U.S.  In the U.S. the term 'turnover' is never used meaning an amount of money.  (You might have employee or inventory turnover).  In the UK, it is common to call what we call in the U.S. revenue - cash coming in - either turnover or income.  The latter is very confusing, because in the U.S. 'income' is revenues minus expenses, or profit.  It's partly accounting.  for the U.S., see: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/r/revenuerecognition.asp and for the UK see: https://www.starfishaccounting.co.uk/what-is-turnover/

Comment: You will actually see that in the UK the term 'turnover' is codified in law (the Companies Act).

Comment: In the USA turnover is definitely used to refer to volume, value of sales in business contexts. Any dictionary will tell you that

Comment: It may be in the dictionary, and you are free to use it, but I have never seen it used that way in the U.S. in business.

Comment: In the US, turnover normally refers to - 1. Retention ponds getting smelly after the spring thaw. 2. Inventory replenishment rate, as in an annual turnover of five. 3. Employee turnover, a measure of employee retention. 4 Apple turnover - tasty. 5. Ecology: species turnover associated with community succession. 6. [Cash Turnover Ratio](https://www.accountingtools.com/articles/cash-turnover-ratio.html), by far the least known. It is specialist jargon.

Comment: This is absolutely right. In business jargon re British accounting English. Where the Brits use ***Turnover*** in annual reports, Americans use **Sales revenue or Sales***. Turnover in US English in business is not seen in annual report accounting per se. And it refers to: product turnover and is an inventory term in the US. Anyone used to reading annual reports will know this. Downvotes on things that are correct irk me. The answer here is generally right.